# Is there a spiritual/symbolic significance as to why the black and white tallis seems to be the standard amongst Orthodox?

Tags: history, tallit-gadol, symbols-symbology

[**The majority of Orthodox Jews I've seen wearing tallit tend to wear this style.**](https://i.pinimg.com/736x/1c/a8/0b/1ca80b6a23dfdd41d8742f532565ae39--jewish-gifts-tallit.jpg)

I was curious if there was any sort of spiritual/symbolic significance associated with this style.

[**The main reason I ask is I once read that the Israeli flag was designed after a Tallis.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Israel#Origin_of_the_flag) The two blue stripes were meant to represent the stripes of of the Tallis on the white banner of the flag. Seeing as how the Israeli flag is blue and not black, I was curious if there was ever a cultural shift that occurred in our history.

Was it possibly to do with the loss of the blue dye of the **techelet**? Thus Jews stopped wearing blue in general as they didn't want to tread on what had been lost?

Comment: Anyone can come up with an explanation after the fact. It isn't hard to predict the past. Are you only looking for sources advocating it before it was popularised, or even those from after?

Comment: White stripes on a white tallis is according to kabala

Comment: @DoubleAA - This is not exactly a duplicate since Avri was asking about spiritual significance and as a matter of fact there is a spititual significance to **not** wearing a Talis with stripes, as the Kabbala praises the one who wears a wholly white Talis which is why many Spharadim wear them.

Comment: @DoubleAA I still appreciate the link to the previously answered question. Thank you very much!